# How to efficiently extract substrings from a string (with - or _)

Tags: python

I have a list of wall names of a building, and it looks like below:

```
wall_list = ['W1_1F-12F', 'W2_1F-9F', 'W3_10F-12F']
```

I want to separate them into three or extract each of the elements (like W1, 1F, 12F) so that I can use wall names or floor information in another process.

```
wall_name = [W1, W2, W3...]
Floor_from = [1F, 1F, 10F...]
Floor_to = [12F, 9F, 12F...]
```

This is the result I want to get in the end.

I think it will be efficient to solve this problem by reading strings before or after `_` and `-`, if this kind of method exists.

Comment: Will the values always follow the same pattern? Like 'Wall_Floor-FloorTo'?

Comment: yes same pattern, but I already solved the problem with the answers below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) version of the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) function with a simple pattern:

```py
import re

wall_list = ['W1_1F-12F', 'W2_1F-9F', 'W3_10F-12F']

for s in wall_list:
    print(re.split('[_-]', s))
```

Which will give:

```
['W1', '1F', '12F']
['W2', '1F', '9F']
['W3', '10F', '12F']
```

And to separate them to elements just put the result into [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
import re

wall_list = ['W1_1F-12F', 'W2_1F-9F', 'W3_10F-12F']

wall, floor_from, floor_to = zip(*(re.split('[_-]', s) for s in wall_list))
print(wall, floor_from, floor_to, sep='\n')
```

Which will now give:

```
('W1', 'W2', 'W3')
('1F', '1F', '10F')
('12F', '9F', '12F')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

def extract_components(wall):
    match = re.match("^(W\d+)_(\d+F)-(\d+F)", wall)
    return match.groups()

def extract(walls):
    return list(zip(*[extract_components(wall) for wall in walls]))

wall_name, floor_from, floor_to = extract(wall_list)
```

Results:

```py
(+) >>> wall_name
('W1', 'W2', 'W3')
(+) >>> floor_from
('1F', '1F', '10F')
(+) >>> floor_to
('12F', '9F', '12F')
```

Comment: Using `^` with `re.match` is redundant. `re.match` by definition matches from the start of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
wall_list = ["W1_1F-12F", "W2_1F-9F", "W3_10F-12F"]
wall_name = [] #[W1, W2, W3...]
Floor_from = [] #[1F, 1F, 10F...]
Floor_to = [] #[12F, 9F, 12F...]
for i in wall_list:
    wall_name.append(i.split("_")[0])
    Floor_from.append(i.split("_")[1].split("-")[0])
    Floor_to.append(i.split("_")[1].split("-")[1])
print(wall_name,Floor_from,Floor_to)
```

Comment: You are doing the same split (`i.split("_")`) three times. That's not so efficient

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
wallList = ["W1_1F-12F", "W2_1F-9F", "W3_10F-12F"]
wallName = []
floorFrom = []
floorTo = []

for element in wallList:
    wallName.append( element.split("_")[0] )
    floorFrom.append( element.split("-")[0].split("_")[1] )
    floorTo.append( element.split("-")[1] )

print(wallName)
print(floorFrom)
print(floorTo)
```

Comment: Your answer is very similar, if not identical to one of the other answers to this question. Would you like to elaborate on how your answer is better than the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

you could convert underlines to dashes and the use a simple split:

```
wall_list = ['W1_1F-12F', 'W2_1F-9F', 'W3_10F-12F']

wall_name,Floor_from,Floor_to = map(list,zip(*(w.replace('_','-').split('-') 
                                               for w in wall_list)))
                                    
print(wall_name)    # ['W1', 'W2', 'W3']
print(Floor_from)   # ['1F', '1F', '10F']
print(Floor_to)     # ['12F', '9F', '12F']
```